# why is my Bamboo pen always drawing and a yellow note pad appears?

Tags: macos, drawing, pen, bamboo

I have had a Bamboo pen and touch tablet for a couple years but have not used it in a long time. Now that I'm trying to use it again it is behaving very strangely. It won't drag anything on my desktop, the minute I try there is this yellow pad that appears and the pen draws a line on it instead of dragging the file. The yellow pad and drawn line disappear the second I lift the pen from the tablet.

The most frustrating is it does the same thing when I try to draw in Photoshop. It won't draw with the paintbrush on my canvas because the minute I try to this yellow pad appears and it draws a line on it instead of on the canvas, which disappears the second I lift the pen from the tablet. It also bizarrely automatically switches from the paintbrush to the automatic selection tool.

Has anyone had this problem? Any suggestions on how to fix this?

I operate with Mac OS X 10.5.8

Comment: Did you manage to fix this problem?

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Lion, but this should be on the same spot in Leopard if I remember correctly.

The yellow pad is Apple's built in handwriting recognition. With your tablet plugged in, go to System Preferences > Ink.

In there, I'd suggest disabling handwriting recognition entirely if you don't use it. That's what I do. You could also try unchecking "Show Ink window" (that's the yellow pad) and "Allow me to ink in any application" to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score -1):

You can enable/disable the quick access floating icon from the Settings dialog box - when the yellow box pops up click on it then on the grey cogs to get to `settings` > `panel options` > uncheck `display quick access button`.